# Uneven margins above and below lstlisting

Tags: listings

The output from the code below looks wrong to me. I am trying to add padding around my listings, but I want the margins to be as thin as possible, preferably matching the space between consecutive lines (thin white space between the yellow lines). For some reason I am unable to make the bottom margin match the top margin. Any ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\lstset
{ basicstyle=\ttfamily
, backgroundcolor=\color{orange}
, frame=tblr
, framerule=0pt
, framesep=0pt
, framextopmargin=1ex
, aboveskip=1ex
, framexbottommargin=1ex
, belowskip=1ex
, framexleftmargin=1.5ex
, xleftmargin=1.5ex
, framexrightmargin=1.5ex
, xrightmargin=1.5ex
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\newline
\hl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("hello world!");
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\hl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\newline
\hl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach aims to set "optically equal" whitespace before and after the listing  (by using the ascenders and descenders in the text lines instead of their baselines).

This space can be controlled by setting `xtspace`.

`\setlength{\xtspace}{<length>}`

Doubling the font size with the same settings shows  the scalability of the solution.

[image: C]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

%************************************************************ added
\newlength{\topshift}
\newlength{\bottomshift}
\newlength{\xmargins}
\newlength{\xtspace}

\setlength{\xtspace}{0.2\baselineskip}% adjust space above and bellow the listing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlength{\xmargins}{0.5\baselineskip} % adjust framextopmargin &  framexbottommargin
\setlength{\topshift}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1em+\xtspace}
\setlength{\bottomshift}{\dimexpr-1ex+\xtspace} 
%************************************************************

\lstset
{ basicstyle=\ttfamily, 
    backgroundcolor=\color{orange},
    frame=tblr,
    framerule=0pt, 
    framesep=0pt,
    framextopmargin=\xmargins,  % changed
    aboveskip=\topshift,        % changed
    framexbottommargin=\xmargins, % changed
    belowskip=\bottomshift,     % changed
    framexleftmargin=1.5ex,
    xleftmargin=1.5ex,
    framexrightmargin=1.5ex,
    xrightmargin=1.5ex
}

\begin{document}
    
\textbf{Fontsize= 10pt}
    
\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont    

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
printf("hello world!");
return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  

\bigskip    

\fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont

\textbf{Fontsize= 20pt}

\setlength{\xtspace}{0.2\baselineskip}% adjust space above and bellow the listing <<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\xmargins}{0.5\baselineskip} % adjust framextopmargin &  framexbottommargin
\setlength{\topshift}{\dimexpr\baselineskip-1em+\xtspace}
\setlength{\bottomshift}{\dimexpr-1ex+\xtspace} 

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#include <stdio>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
printf("hello world!");
return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\newline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks promising. But why does it work? How did you determine the formulas for the various lengths? Did you manually draw the turquoise lines?